# Heroku Scheduled Python Script Crashes Every Few Days

Tags: python, heroku

I have a script that runs for 16 hours a day on heroku. On most days, it works great, but every now and then it crashes with this error. I have not been able to narrow down why. Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
2021-04-28T18:44:48.341436+00:00 app[scheduler.8000]:     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
2021-04-28T18:44:48.341527+00:00 app[scheduler.8000]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
2021-04-28T18:44:48.342196+00:00 app[scheduler.8000]:     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
2021-04-28T18:44:48.342230+00:00 app[scheduler.8000]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
2021-04-28T18:44:48.342942+00:00 app[scheduler.8000]:     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
2021-04-28T18:44:48.342974+00:00 app[scheduler.8000]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
2021-04-28T18:44:48.343545+00:00 app[scheduler.8000]:     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
2021-04-28T18:44:48.343756+00:00 app[scheduler.8000]: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Logging in requires two steps, here is the post and get process:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
  def connect():
    r = s.post(DEFAULT_LOGIN_URL, headers=default_login_headers, data=default_data)
    time.sleep(2)
    r = s.post(LOGIN_URL, headers=login_headers, data=login_data)
    time.sleep(2)
  
  def get_page():
    # failing to get the page usually means the user was logged out
    try:
      page = s.get(URL, headers=headers)
      time.sleep(2)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
      # other stuff done with the page content
    except:
      connect()

  connect()
  while(true):
    get_page()
    time.sleep(60)
```

requirements.txt:

```
arrow==1.0.3     
astroid==2.5.1     
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3     
binaryornot==0.4.4     
bs4==0.0.1     
certifi==2020.12.5 
chardet==4.0.0     
click==7.1.2     
colorama==0.4.4     
cookiecutter==1.7.2     
cookiejar==0.0.3     
cycler==0.10.0    
dateparser==1.0.0
decorator==4.0.11
dnspython==2.1.0
html5lib==1.1
idna==2.10
isort==5.7.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jinja2-time==0.2.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.5.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mechanize==0.4.5
pager==3.3
pandas==1.2.3
Pillow==8.1.2
poyo==0.5.0
psaw==0.1.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.7.2
pymongo==3.11.3
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-slugify==4.0.1
pytz==2021.1
regex==2020.11.13
requests==2.25.1
six==1.10.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
text-unidecode==1.3
times==0.7
toml==0.10.2
twilio==6.56.0
tzlocal==2.1
update-checker==0.18.0
urllib3==1.26.4
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.58.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Comment: The log snippet you posted doesn't show where in your code the error occurred. You've got 2 POST requests and 1 GET request. Could be any of them. Since the failure only occurs every few days, it's more likely in `get_page()`. Once you've connected on day 1 and got a session, there's no reason to assume your session _never_ expires. Add a check in `get_page()` to run `connect()` every 12 hrs or 24 hrs so you always have an updated session. 'Connection aborted' might mean the other server is blocking; rather than failed credentials. Impossible to say from the details provided.

Comment: Also, you're executing `connect()` from `get_page()` when there's _any_ failure. Instead, log the error instead of a bare `except` clause. And don't define functions under `with`. Return the session object `s` from `connect()` and use it in `get_page()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As you can probably guess, this is my first Python project. So your input is much appreciated.